# Vuejs - global store setting

Tags: vue.js, global-variables, vuex

I have a global store setting which determines which user role could be 'admin', 'editor' or 'junior-editor'.

A the moment I have to import my store and use make the store variable available in the data.

Is there a way to expose this al all my components?

Comment: by global store do you mean vuex? if vuex then it is available in all components by default

Comment: Please provide more information about your environment. Which store? Which format is global store settings? Would be nice if you could setup a minimal example at https://stackblitz.com/ any similar code sharing site

Answer (score 1):

If using Vuex, you can call it on any component using:
this.$store

For example, in an app with a "user" module and the data is called "role", it would be:

this.$store.state.user.role

There is no need to import store into each component. It should be injected in your main app file (main.js or index.js), like:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store
})
```

Comment: and what do you do if your component is defined before the vue instance and you need to access store inside the component

Comment: @PirateApp import store in the component is my guess, but I don't see how that setup makes sense